# cant import a js bit component into a ts project - `Could not find a declaration file for module`

Tags: javascript, typescript, bit.dev

when trying to npm install a javascript component into a typescript project, I get a typescript error for missing the `d.ts` file or a `@types` component:

```
TypeScript error in /Users/oded/code/base-components/src/App.tsx(3,33):
Could not find a declaration file for module '@bit/bit.web.components.comment-carousel'. '/Users/oded/code/base-components/node_modules/@bit/bit.web.components.comment-carousel/dist/src/components/comment-carousel/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/bit.web.components.comment-carousel` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@bit/bit.web.components.comment-carousel';
```

I am the author of the `@bit/bit.web.components.comment-carousel` component in a different project.

There are 2 ways I can think of to resolve this:

1. I can `bit eject` it from the author project it was first written in (and where it is currently used), and add a `d.ts` to the component.
2. I can `bit import` the component and modify it in my consuming project but it feels like a bit of an overkill.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I think is not a Bit issue, but a TypeScript issue, maybe you can add the directory of the imported components to the exclude option of the `tsconfig.json`

Comment: excluding `node_modules` in the `tsconfig.json` didnt work for me.
see the following [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14028).   

what worked for me was adding `@ts-ignore` over the import of the component.



```js

//@ts-ignore
import { CommentCarousel } from "@bit/bit.web.components.comment-carousel";
```